# Wordpress ACF fields not displaying

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem with displaying ACF group fields in wordpress theme.

I have a group of fields named "grupapakiety" that is assigned to the specific page named "Strona główna". I want to display fields of this group in the front-page.php theme file.

I've already tried adding page id to the get_field of the group, but it didn't work.

Repeater field from this group named "pakiety" doesn't work either.

```
<?php $pakiety = get_field('grupapakiety'); if ($pakiety['czy_pokazywac_pole_z_pakietami']) { ?>
<!-------------------------------- Pricing plan -------------------------------->
<div class="px-4 py-16 mx-auto sm:max-w-xl md:max-w-full lg:max-w-screen-xl md:px-24 lg:px-8 lg:py-20">
  <div class="max-w-xl mb-10 md:mx-auto sm:text-center lg:max-w-2xl md:mb-12">
    <div>
      <p class="inline-block px-3 py-px mb-4 text-xs font-semibold tracking-wider text-teal-900 uppercase rounded-full bg-teal-accent-400">
        <?php echo $pakiety['pakiety_subtitle']; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <h2 class="max-w-lg mb-6 font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl md:mx-auto">
      <span class="relative inline-block">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 52 24" fill="currentColor" class="absolute top-0 left-0 z-0 hidden w-32 -mt-8 -ml-20 text-blue-gray-100 lg:w-32 lg:-ml-28 lg:-mt-10 sm:block">
          <defs>
            <pattern id="7e5e8ff8-1960-4094-a63a-2a0c0f922d69" x="0" y="0" width=".135" height=".30">
              <circle cx="1" cy="1" r=".7"></circle>
            </pattern>
          </defs>
          <rect fill="url(#7e5e8ff8-1960-4094-a63a-2a0c0f922d69)" width="52" height="24"></rect>
        </svg>
      </span>
      <?php echo $pakiety['pakiety_title']; ?>
    </h2>
    <p class="text-base text-gray-700 md:text-lg">
      <?php echo $pakiety['pakiety_tekst']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  

<div class="grid max-w-md gap-10 row-gap-5 lg:max-w-screen-lg sm:row-gap-10 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:max-w-screen-lg sm:mx-auto">
<?php
if (have_rows('pakiety')):
  while (have_rows('pakiety')): the_row();

$nazwapakietu = get_sub_field('nazwa_pakietu');
$cenapakietu = get_sub_field('cena_pakietu');
$okres = get_sub_field('za_jaki_okres_przysluguje_dana_cena');
$CTAtext = get_sub_field('cta_text');
$CTAurl = get_sub_field('cta_url');
$opispakietu = get_sub_field('opis_pakietu');
$pakietpopularny = get_sub_field('czy_pakiet_ma_byc_oznaczony_jako_najbardziej_popularny');
$popularnytekst = get_sub_field('tekst_najbardziej_popularny');

?>

<div class="flex flex-col justify-between p-8 transition-shadow duration-300 bg-white border rounded shadow-sm sm:items-center hover:shadow <?php if($pakietpopularny) { ?>border-[#6421fb]<?php } ?>">
    <?php if($pakietpopularny) { ?>
      <div class="absolute inset-x-0 top-0 flex justify-center -mt-3">
        <div class="inline-block px-3 py-1 text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-white uppercase rounded bg-[#6421fb]">
          <?php echo $popularnytekst; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
      <div class="text-center">
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold"><?php echo $nazwapakietu; ?></div>
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center mt-2">
          <div class="mr-1 text-5xl font-bold"><?php echo $cenapakietu; ?></div>
          <div class="text-gray-700"><?php echo $okres; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2 space-y-3">
        <?php
            if (have_rows('co_wchodzi_w_sklad_pakietu')):
            while (have_rows('co_wchodzi_w_sklad_pakietu')): the_row();
            $funkcjonalnosc = get_sub_field('funkcjonalnosc');
        ?>
          <div class="text-gray-700"><?php echo $funkcjonalnosc; ?></div>
        <?php
            endwhile;
            endif; 
        ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $CTAurl; ?>" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-full h-12 px-6 mt-6 font-medium tracking-wide text-white transition duration-200<?php if($pakietpopularny) { ?> bg-[#6421fb] hover:bg-[#4c1fb3] <?php } else { ?> bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900 <?php } ?>rounded shadow-md focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none">
          <?php echo $CTAtext; ?>
        </a>
        <p class="max-w-xs mt-6 text-xs text-gray-600 sm:text-sm sm:text-center sm:max-w-sm sm:mx-auto">
          <?php echo $opispakietu; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php

endwhile;
endif; 
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the page `"Strona główna"` set as the front-page? Repeaters in groups work in the same manner as *nested repeaters*: loop with `have_rows` through the group and **then** loop through the repeater with `have_rows`.

Comment: "Strona główna" is set as the main page in wordpress view settings.

Comment: And is the `$pakiety['czy_pokazywac_pole_z_pakietami']` value `1` and correctly implemented? What if you remove that `if` statement?

Comment: Yes, it has value 1. If I remove the if statement the widget shows, but still without the fields value.